# Why this if statment only work at first step

Tags: prolog

```
calculateSum(_, _List, _Row, _Col, []).
    calculateSum([M|Rest],List,Row,Col,[Y|Tail]):-
    Col == Row -> Col1 is Col + 1,calculateSum(List,List,Row1,Col1,Tail); 
    calcHeu(Rest,L),
    sum(L,S),
    index(List, Row, Col, V),
    Y is V + S,
    %Row1 is Row + 1,
     Col1 is Col + 1,
    calculateSum(List,List,Row1,Col1,Tail).
```

Why this Col == Row if statement doest work. Is there any other way so that if Row == Col skip that step?

### EDIT

By doing some thing like this.

```
(Col \= Row ->
calcHeu(Rest,L),
sum(L,S),
index(List, Row, Col, V),
Y is V + S,
Col1 is Col + 1,
calculateSum(List,List,Row1,Col1,Tail)
;
Col1 is Col + 1,calculateSum(List,List,Row1,Col1,Tail)
).
```

it print out [22,*,*,_...... infinitly

Comment: Which parameter values are you passing in?

Comment: @sll | ?-matrix(X),calculateSum(X,X,3,2,Z).
where matrix([[dada],[dadada],[dada]] It should not calculate 3 3

Comment: regardless of why it works/doesn't work, you should really make 2 different clauses in such a case. It's difficult to parse in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what your code is supposed to do and what inputs it gets, but you can definitely break your if-then-else statement into two rules with a cut (which in my opinion is preferable anyways: try to avoid using ";" as much as possible).

Try this (note that I've change the fir occurrence of "List" in the recursive call for "Rest", because I think that's what you want anyways):

```
calculateSum(_, _List, _Row, _Col, []).
calculateSum([_M|Rest],List,Row,Row,[_Y|Tail]):-
    !,
    Col1 is Col + 1,
    calculateSum(Rest,List,Row1,Col1,Tail).

calculateSum([M|Rest],List,Row,Col,[Y|Tail]):-
    calcHeu(Rest,L),
    sum(L,S),
    index(List, Row, Col, V),
    Y is V + S,
    Col1 is Col + 1,
    calculateSum(Rest,List,Row1,Col1,Tail).
```